# Брать ли слова в кавычки в вопросе о том, что это?

Tags: кавычки

Если ставится вопрос (в игре, предполагающей варианты ответа) об определении, например, понятия "русский язык" —

что называют русским языком,

что такое русский язык,

что называют словами русский язык —

то надо ли заключать эти слова в кавычки? От чего это зависит? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В перечисленных вариантах кавычки не нужны, потому что это общеизвестный термин, по правилам в кавычки берут слова непривычные, малоупотребительные, термины тоже только малоизвестные, употреблённые в ироническом значении, условном значении, большую часть названий, цитаты.

Можно взять в кавычки это сочетание как название курса, официальное название учебного предмета:

Рабочая программа по предмету "Русский язык" или "Русский язык и литература". Но:  Русский язык как предмет - это...

Answer (score 1):

> что называют русским языком,
> что такое русский язык,

Не вижу причин для кавычек. Речь идет о собственно объекте.

> что называют словами русский язык

А здесь кавычки нужны: **«Что называют словами "русский язык"?»**
По крайней мере в случае, если это реальный вопрос. Здесь говорится о словах, то есть не о русском языке, а о **названии** некоторого объекта. То, что этот термин общепринят и общепонятен не отменяет необходимость кавычек.

***Что называется словом "яблоко"?*** - попробуйте написать без кавычек - не сразу и смысл дойдет.

И примеры из нацкорпуса.

> Раздельное существование наций, как известно, называется словом
> «апартеид»

("Коммерсант")

> Мысль пойти в гости или где-нибудь выпить ― это не называется словом
> «мысли».

Александр Клейн. Виктор Шендерович // «Пятое измерение», 2002

Таких примеров можно найти еще. Есть, правда, единственный, отчасти подтверждающий точку зрения Людмилы.

> чтобы делать его реальным, выращивать из идеального ребенка (жениха)
> реального мужа, ― все это называется словом лад

Пришвин, дневники.

Пример сомнительный, ибо тут как бы "вводится" это понятие - и уже поэтому кавычки нужны.